# how to resize SVG PATH shape?

Tags: javascript, svg

I am working on an app that creates SVG shapes ( to represent a room ) using SVG.js library

[image: Created Shapes using Path]

When to user clicks on a shape , it gets added to the screen , i have managed to successfully create them using PATH element in SVG

the problem i have is i want to resize them , for the rectangle and circle elements it's straighforward i could easily manipulate the width and height or rectangle to resize it , and the diameter for the circle element.

the problem is with the other shapes, because manipulating a PATH totally messed up the shape.

to get the idea of what excatly try to achieve . play arround with the shapes and resize them on this site : [ http://cuisine3d.leroymerlin.fr/public/Apps/idealspaces/?kioskMode=false&portalMode=OAA&locationCode=30#inspiration/aR43fH1-f2A/measure ]

any advice would be very welcoming .

Comment: Doesn’t SVG.js have a [scale](http://svgjs.com/manipulating/#scale) transform?

Comment: @MarkMeyer yes it does , but that's what am looking for i want to be able to resize each side of the shape individually. the scale function only resize the shape as a whole . which i already done

Comment: If you are trying to duplicate the functionality of that other site (dragging of corners and walls etc) then your question is too broad. That's too big a problem to answer succinctly here.